# Estimation of population minimum from sample

Tags: statistics

Given a sample of values $[x_1, x_2, ..., x_k]$ drawn from an unknown population $P$, how can we effectively estimate the minimum of $P$?

I am interested in the general case where the distribution of $P$ is unknown, and the case where $P$ is taken from a normal distribution.

Comment: Well, there is _no_ theoretical minimum for any normal distribution. Normal distributions are often used as approximate probability models for test scores, human heights, and so on. Then the practical minimum is $0$ (which should be several standard deviations $\sigma$ below the mean $\mu).$ // Some distributions, such as those in gamma (including exponential) and Weibull families have $0$ or some shift constant $\theta$ as theoretical population minimum. Then the sample minimum is often used to estimate the population minimum. // For a more helpful answer, I suggest you clarify your question.

Comment: @BruceET Perhaps some context will help? I frequently am given a series of real numbers, when I need a series of non-negative numbers. The naïve solution is to subtract the sample minimum. However, this has a number of undesirable properties. For example, given values $\vec{v} = [1, 0]$ and weights $\vec{w} = [-1, 0]$, we want the weighted sum but require non-negative weights. Using the above strategy, $1 * (-1 - -1) + 0 * (0 - -1) = 0$.

Comment: @BruceET If we instead subtract the minimum - 1, $1 * (-1 - (-1 - 1)) + 0 * (0 - (-1 - 1)) = 1$, but now decreasing $\vec{w}_1$ does not change the result. $1 * (-2 - (-2 - 1)) + 0 * (0 - (-2 - 1)) = 1$. If the population minimum $P_{min}$ is known, subtracting $P_{min}$ resolves these undesirable properties. Given $P_{min} = -3$, $1 * (-1 - P_{min}) + 0 * (0 - P_{min}) = 2 > 1 * (-2 - P_{min}) + 0 * (0 - P_{min}) = 1$.

Comment: @BruceET Also, it is worth noting that while a normal distribution has no minimum, any finite population taken from a normal distribution does have a minimum. We should be able to estimate the population minimum given a sample from that population.

Comment: Thanks for the context. But I'm still having trouble figuring out  how you're defining the desired minimum. Maybe someone who has encountered a similar situation can be of help.